# iPhone GLSL dynamic branching behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, branch, glsl, shader

I know that branching is not a good idea of writing shaders, but I haven't thought of a way to avoid it. Here is my fragment shader code:

```
precision highp float;

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec4 v_pos;

uniform int u_numberOfParticles;

uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;

uniform vec3 u_waterVertices[100];

void main()
{
    vec4 finalColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    vec2 currPos = v_pos.xy;

    float accum = 0.0;
    vec3 normal = vec3(0, 0, 0);

    for ( int i = 0; i < u_numberOfParticles; ++i )
    {
        // Some calculations here
    }
    normal = normalize(normal);

    float normalizeToEdge = 1.0 - (accum - threshold) / 2.0;

    if (normalizeToEdge < 0.3)
        finalColor = vec4( 0.1, normalizeToEdge + 0.5, 0.9-normalizeToEdge*0.4, 1.0);

    if ( normalizeToEdge < 0.2 )
    {
        finalColor = vec4( 120.0/255.0, 245.0/255.0, 245.0/255.0, 1.0);
        float shade = mix( 0.7, 1.0, normal.x);
        finalColor *= shade;
    }


    gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColor);

}
```

The problem is here :

```
for ( int i = 0; i < u_numberOfParticles; ++i )
{
     // Some calculations here
}
```

changing it to :

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i )
{
    // Some calculations here
}
```

doubles the framerate even though u_numberOfParticles is also 2;

changing it to

```
   for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
   {
       if( i == u_numberOfParticles)
            break;
       // Some calculations here
   }
```

doesn't provide any fps improvements.

How can I cope with such shader behaviour? Is there any techiques to avoid this branching? I think that it will be inefficient to write 50 different shaders for the different number of particles... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you put the constant there, the compiler might feel the need to optimize the loop to "do 2 times the same in a row" which may result in the performance gain. the dynamic variable is dynamic and can not be optimized for at compile time.

Comment: @scones but I think there should be a solution that people use to deal with such problems. I just can't make it constant because the number of particles vary on different situations.